# Can Google App Engine make a http request to a Compute Engine instance within the same project without an external IP?

Tags: google-app-engine, http, google-compute-engine

In App Engine I'd like to make http fetch calls to a web server running on an Compute Engine instance, created within the same Google cloud project, and I'm wondering if I can make such calls to the instance without enabling an external IP for it?  Are App Engine and Compute Engine instances, from the same project, within the same network and can I call a Compute Engine instance by name from App Engine?

Comment: I don't know the answer, however there may be some overlap with this  App Engine VM-based Backends  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/gRZNqlQPKys

Comment: Thanks, Tim, for pointing this out.  _App Engine VM-based Backends_ may in fact be exactly what I'm looking for, because I need to use Java libraries that depend on classes that are outside App Engine's sandbox (whitelist) and that brought me to consider GCE but those appengine-vm-backends might be a better fit if I can communicate in a more _internal_ way than using the URLFetch API and public IPs.  I've now signed up as a tester and await reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently unsupported.  Communication between App Engine and GCE must go through the URLFetch API and use a public IP.

Comment: Thanks, Joe, for the answer.  Do I understand the upcoming App Engine VM backends correctly, that Tim points out here, in that they would allow me to make direct API calls to libraries running there from my regular App Engine code?

Comment: @Joe any update on that. I want to migrate part of my services from compute to app engine and need this functionality . any way this can be supported? vpn maybe?

Answer (score 6):

The best way to solve that in the short/medium term is to deploy the VM as a VM-based backend ([we are accepting TT applications](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/gRZNqlQPKys)). You can deploy the VM backend as a different App Engine module of the app. Then you can urlfetch "mymodule.myapp.appspot.com" from the frontend and it will hit your VM without going through the public IP.

You can also serve your app straight from the VM backend. There you can load classes that are blocked by the normal App Engine sandbox (and well as have full access to all App Engine APIs!). The downside with VM backends is that we don't have auto-scaling yet.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.  After Tim Hoffman's suggestion I filled out this form a few weeks ago, but haven't received a repsonse:  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1NTPROehZLn7lzu3pcXryB8BlZN5cu0SwiIzPnl35xHs/viewform  - if my TT application will be accepted, where can I find documentation on how to create and deploy a VM backend as an App Engine module?  Sounds like an interesting configuration that I would like to try :)

Comment: Thanks for this info. What happens if the VM goes offline due to scheduled maintenance ? Do I (as an app developer) need to build this redundancy myself ?