# Google AppEngine communicating with Compute Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I want to be able to send a command from Google AppEngine to my Compute Engine.

More specifically, I want to install pdftk on my Compute Engine and be able to send data to the Compute Engine through my Google App Engine.

- Google App Engine receives data
- Google App Engine sends data to Compute Engine
- Compute Engine runs pdftk, creates the PDF, maybe uploads it to Google Cloud Storage or sends it back to Google App Engine where Google App Engine uploads it
- Google App Engine sends temporary public link to the file.

I'm just having trouble figuring out how to link my AppEngine with my Compute engine.

I want to be able to do this in PHP. Could anyone point me to some **examples**. I have looked through all the API Reference stuff but I don't really understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An App Engine instance can talk to a Compute Engine instance the same way as any two servers talk to each other over the Internet, for example, by using GET and POST http requests.

If instances belong to different projects, you will need to use a public Ip address for your Compute Engine instances. See for more details: 
[Can Google App Engine make a http request to a Compute Engine instance within the same project without an external IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060762/can-google-app-engine-make-a-http-request-to-a-compute-engine-instance-within-th)

Comment: So I'd have to install apache and all that for it to communicate with each other? I can't just send a command?

Comment: There is no need to install apache. Look at the second answer in the question that I linked.

Comment: I don't think this is available for PHP app engine

Comment: I appreciate the help, but just linking to url fetch just confuses me more haha. I know what it is and I use it many times in my app engine to do basic website requests, but I do not understand how I would send commands to a server that doesn't have apache using url fetch.

Comment: @bryan: You said "it's not available". I gave you the link. As for the confusion, you do need a web server.

Comment: thank you for clearing that up. I appreciate your help

Comment: Other answers suggest you need to go through an external IP even if the GAE application and GCE VM are on the same network.  Can anyone confirm or deny?

Comment: You can only access a stand-alone GCE VM instance via its external IP address, or use some form of load-balancing. You don't need an external IP address for managed VM instances, if I understand correctly.