# How do I connect my App Engine front end to my Compute Engine back end?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I have an App Engine front end that needs to communicate via JDBC to a database running on Compute Engine. It can't seem to connect via the internal IP. What do I need to change or configure? This is NOT the same as issue - stackoverflow.com/questions/20060762/…  because URLFetch is a very specific Google Cloud service. It is my understanding that even GCE outgoing http requests are currently forced through this service. This should not apply to port 3306 though.

Comment: Have you configured mysql access?  There are a lot of links out there on how to do that if you haven't so far.  [Here is a quick Rackspace tutorial](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely).

Comment: Also, have you considered using [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction)?  You can configure access in the Google Cloud Dashboard, utilize backups, etc.

Comment: We use Google Cloud SQL for some things, and MariaDB running on Compute Engine for others (more complex connectivity requirements). App Engine can connect to the MariaDB on Compute Engine no problem using the EXTERNAL IP address, just not the INTERNAL IP address. Yes, this is all on the same project. Of course I don't want to use the External IP for cost and performance reasons.

Comment: See -- essentially the same Qs -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060762/can-google-app-engine-make-a-http-request-to-a-compute-engine-instance-within-th -- with good answers AND a suggested workaround based on MVMs.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Those answers are two years old... certainly they must have fixed this very obvious limitation!

Comment: After much research and head scratching, it appears that as of now App Engine can only access Compute Engine through its EXTERNAL IP Address. This is unfortunate because I can see many, many apps that would ideally want an App Engine front end (auto scaling) talking to a back end on Compute Engine. Going through the External IP adds significant latency. Hope Google fixes this!