# AppEngine Multi backends keeping autoscaling

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an AppEngine webapp with a JavaScript **tracker**. I want it to make HTTP calls to a **collector** (which is a REST API that saves data into BigQuery) without making an entire app-to-app authentication process with OAuth/JWT or whatever.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060762/can-google-app-engine-make-a-http-request-to-a-compute-engine-instance-within-th) it's not possible for AppEngine to use a REST API located on a compute engine instance with an internal IP.

In addition, it seems that it's not possible to use GAE multibackends feature since it **loses autoscaling** and I really need this feature.

What is the proper Google Cloud way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the collector is running on compute engine and the problem is how to verify that requests to the collector are genuine requests from the AppEngine service since the only way for the AppEngine app to reach the collector is via a public IP.

AppEngine has an Identity API for an AppEngine to assert to a [third party service that a request is genuine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_third-party_services). A more detailed (and less contrived) example of how to use this is [discussed here](https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/authenticate-google-app-engine-app). The code link no longer works but the code is available [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/app-identity-samples/source/default/source).

This specific sequence from the last article seems to be more or less what you need:

> - Client App generates a signed blob by calling app_identity.signForApp(string_blob)
> - Client App exposes its public certificates on a public endpoint, for example clientapp.com/certs.  In the demos below we use a trivial Json format to expose certificates, something like: {"cert1":"x509 cert pem", "cert2":"x509 cert pem 2"...}.
> - Client App sends a request to API App along with the signed blob and the URL that contains Client App's public certificates.
> - API App fetches Client App's public certificates from that URL
> - API App verifies the signature of the signed blob.  The API App might perform other business logic like checking if the Client App (as identified by the URL of its public certificates) is on an access control list.
> - Both apps should agree on the same 'signed blob' format.  In our demo we use JWT as the signed token format. The detailed spec can be found at http://self-issued.info/