# Dispatching App Engine url to a Compute Engine instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-launcher

I have

- a working website hosted on App Engine (python)... on let's say `domain.com`
- a working Wordpress on some IP address created with Cloud Launcher on Compute Engine

Both are within one Google Cloud project.

What I want is to have `domain.com/blog` show the Wordpress from the GCE instance. I thought the `dispatch.yaml` should be able to do this, but it seems it works only for GAE modules/services.

Is it possible to redirect */blog from GAE to a GCE instance?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20082588/5537109) indicates that GCE instances must be accessed via external IP addresses from the Google App Engine.

That suggests that it is not possible to redirect those calls to GCE instances via dispatch.yml directly.

You could try having the App Engine either issue a [Server side redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_redirect) to your GCE instance or else maybe get the content from the GCE instance itself and return it to the user.